# CPanel - how to add a website inside the public_html folder of another website?

Tags: apache, permissions, cpanel

I am trying to add a website inside another website's public_html folder.

The reason for this is we would like to use one admin system for both websites and would need to be able to access both website directories for images etc.

I have tried the following:

Created a new user
Modified /var/cpanel/userdata/USERNAME/DOMAIN.COM and changed document root
Rebuilt using /scripts/rebuildhttpdconf
Restarted HTTPD server

Having done so (I would have expected it to work!) But I keep getting an internal server error 500.

Digging around and checking the error logs I found the following error:

SoftException in Application.cpp:592: Directory /home/master-username/public_html is not owned by username (the username of the new account I am trying to add inside public_html)

Any other ways to go about this? I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have answered my own question. Under the HTTPD config there is a username assigned for the virtual host for the slave domain you can say.

You need to change this username to the master domain's username (the main website).

This seems to have worked for me. Just going to upload the website files and confirm!